# VirtualAlloc and Python - Access Violation

Tags: python, virtualalloc

Very simple python script is giving me an access violation and I just can't figure out why.

```
import ctypes

def Test():
     data = bytearray( "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\x0B\xAD\xC0\xDE", 'utf-16' )
     dataLen = len( data )

     try :
        ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc( ctypes.c_int( 0 ),
                                                   ctypes.c_int( dataLen ),
                                                   ctypes.c_int( 0x3000 ),
                                                   ctypes.c_int( 0x40 ) )

        buf = ( ctypes.c_char * dataLen ).from_buffer( data )

        ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory( ctypes.c_int( ptr ),
                                              buf,
                                              ctypes.c_int( dataLen ) )
     except Exception as e :
        print( e )
        exit(-1)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\_local.py", line 64, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\_local.py", line 125, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\vs17\..\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1099, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1106, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\vs17\...\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:\Dev\Python\VirtualAlloc_Testing\VirtualAlloc_Testing.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Dev\Python\VirtualAlloc_Testing\VirtualAlloc_Testing.py", line 29, in main
    Test()
  File "D:\Dev\Python\VirtualAlloc_Testing\VirtualAlloc_Testing.py", line 19, in Test
    ctypes.c_int( dataLen ) )
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000212F0000
```

Comment: Why use `except Exception` like that? Please share the entire error message.

Comment: @AMC - Thanks for the response:

* OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000212F0000

Comment: I wrote a C++ version of the above and that works just fine. For some reason it doesn't work under Python.

Answer (score 5):

Hit the same issue. For me the reason was wrong `VirtualAlloc` `restype` size, defined as 32-bit value.

Indeed, ctypes functions are not prototyped and return C default type: `c_int`. On Windows, `c_int` is an alias for `c_long` which is a signed 32-bit integer. So when a system allocates a memory block above x32 limit the address returned by VirtualAlloc is cut.

In your case `VirtualAlloc` could return `0000001A212F0000` for example, but then only lower part `0x212F0000` was used as value for `ptr`.

Add the next line before use:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
```

The same stuff is about `RtlCopyMemory.argtypes`:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlCopyMemory.argtypes = ( ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t )
```

works good

Comment: Amazing, tyvm.   OP, please validate and accept this answer.